# how to disable items from different blocks in oracle form?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracleforms, oraclereports

Need your help in a situation.
I am working in a module which has 2 different blocks.
I want to disable the buttons of second block depending upon the option I choose in first block.

For example : If I am choosing “Save” Button in first block the “View” button in Second should be disabled. If I am pressing “Show” Button in first block the “Update” button in Second should be disabled.

I have tried using the set_item_property for the same, but I am getting “unable to reference” Error.

Please suggest how can I disable Item in 1 block through buttons in another block?

Comment: Have you prefixed the name of the item with the name of the block? Show us the code.

Comment: set_item_property('blockname.itemname', visible,property_false);

Answer (score 0):

you may have following in the content of `block1.b_save.WHEN-BUTTON_PRESSED` trigger to `disable`:

```
set_item_property('block2.b_view',enabled,property_false);
```

but don't forget to enable back by

```
set_item_property('block2.b_view',enabled,property_true);
```

whenever you need.

You may apply the same to the other elements you'd like.

Comment: Sir, the problem is I am not able to disable the button. As of now I don't need to enable that

Comment: @AnirudhSengupta ok, the first statement `set_item_property('block2.b_view',enabled,property_false)` stands for `disable`, the second one is just to `enable` back.